# Yocto / Qt 5.6 - QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded

Tags: qt, sqlite, yocto

I am working on Nitrogen6x board that runs on `Yocto 2.1` with `Qt 5.6.2` support. 
I have developed a Qt application that reads data from a Sql database, but I started noticing the below error when I launch my application on target.

```
QSQLITE driver not loaded 
QSqlDatabase: available drivers:
```

As I understand it, this means that I do not have the QSQLITE driver (plugin) built and installed on my target system. I did a simple search to find sql plugin on my target machine and I got the below dump:

```
~ # find / -name *sql*
/usr/bin/sqlite3
/usr/lib/rpm/qf/wdj_l10n_sqlite
/usr/lib/rpm/qf/yum_primary_sqlite
/usr/lib/rpm/qf/yum_other_sqlite
/usr/lib/rpm/qf/yum_filelists_sqlite
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so
/usr/share/mime/application/x-sqlite3.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/x-kexiproject-sqlite3.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/x-sqlite2.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/sql.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/x-kexiproject-sqlite2.xml
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/.debug/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libsqlite3.la
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/.debug/_sqlite3.so
```

I read through some online posts and as I understand I would expect something like `sqldrivers/libqsqlite.so` to be present under

```
/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/plugins
```

to resolve this error ?

I wanted to set my yocto build to create the QSQLITE driver plugin for the target file system. Any help on this is deeply appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added `PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtbase = " sql-sqlite"` in my local.conf. Later, I did `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` and the build was successful.

After extracting the SDK I did not find the `/sqldrivers/` under `/usr/lib/qt5/plugins` but the problem was resolved and my Qt application is now able to read the SQL database.